# How to set class atributes for all objects?

Tags: python

What is a proper way to set an class atribute which is valid for all objects and the class itself?

My Code looks like this:

```py
class Bacteria(Contour):
    min_bacteria_size = 22.56 * 10 ** -15

    def __init__(self, contour):
        super().__init__(contour.contour, contour.hierarchy)
        self.area = contour.area
        self.mean_gray = contour.mean_gray
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(self.contour)
        self.center = rect[0]
        self.width = rect[1][0]
        self.height = rect[1][1]
        self.rotation = rect[2]

    @property
    def min_bacteria_size(self):
        return Bacteria.min_bacteria_size

    @min_bacteria_size.setter
    def min_bacteria_size(self, min_bacteria_size):
        # min_bacteria_size in fm²
        self.min_bacteria_size = min_bacteria_size * 10 ** -15
```

For `min_bacteria_size` there is default value, but it should be possible to change this value for all objects and the class itself. Since i want to set the variable `min_bacteria_size` in femto (10^-15) units i tried to use property setter but it doesn´t worked:

```
Bacteria.min_bacteria_size = 50
print(Bacteria.min_bacteria_size)
>> 50
```

Comment: you have already answered your question. Setters must be used only for assigning values to attributes of _instantiated_ objects of the class. Class variables are not tied to any object and `classname.classvar=val` is correct.

Comment: `def set_min_bacteria_size()` should be decorated with `@staticmethod`, since it doesn't apply to any specific instance of the class, and therefore should lack the `self` parameter.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It seems you already have working code. The Pythonic improvement is using a ``property`` – which you say you have tried already but don't say in how far "it doesn´t worked". So we cannot recommend it (you already know it), but we also cannot tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Are you asking how to define a ``property`` that works on the class?

Comment: @jasonharper you are right. That was a leftover from the property setter

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear question. I clearified my problem in my question.

Comment: Just to be clear: After ``Bacteria.min_bacteria_size = 50`` you want ``Bacteria.min_bacteria_size == 5e-14`` to be true? Be aware that this might be seen as confusing – and thus unpythonic – out of principle since the value set is not the value retrieved.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes that´s right. I undestand your point, but - correct me if i am wrong - i think this happens often when using properties. For instance if i avoid setting `temperature` lower then 0 Kelvin with a property.setter i also have not the retrieved value after excuting `object.temperature = -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost just right - just two points of confusion: the name of
the class attribute where the value is stored *must not* be the same name as the property itself.

The major problem with your code is that when you create the property, you overwrite the default class value. Then your setter sets the new value to the instance only (`self.min_bacteria-size`) - instead of the class (`self.__class__.min_bacteria_size`) - however, if it were written exactly like that, it would overwrite the property itself - so it could be used only once.

Then, there is a 3rdy point, if you will sometimes to see the value in raw meters (the number already multiplied by 10e-15) and sometimes the number in femtometers (the human friendly "50") - you should make BOTH numbers available when reading from the class instances (even if the raw pre-multiplied metric value is only used internally by the class).

So, one way to go is to have an ordinary class attribute which holds the raw value in meters, and a property that will scale and store *that same attribute*, to be consumed by the code that uses the class:

```py
class Bacteria(Contour):
    min_bacteria_size_raw = 22.56 * 10e-15

    def __init__(self, contour):
        ...

    @property
    def min_bacteria_size(self):
        return self.__class__.min_bacteria_size_raw / 10e-15

    @min_bacteria_size.setter
    def min_bacteria_size(self, min_bacteria_size):
        # min_bacteria_size in fm²
        self.__class__.min_bacteria_size_raw = min_bacteria_size * 10e-15
```

And here is the class working (with a dummy "contour" class) on the interactive prompt:

```py
In [9]: b = Bacteria(1)                                                                                                   

In [10]: b.min_bacteria_size                                                                                              
Out[10]: 22.56

In [11]: b.min_bacteria_size = 50                                                                                         

In [12]: b.min_bacteria_size                                                                                              
Out[12]: 50.0

In [13]: b.min_bacteria_size_raw                                                                                          
Out[13]: 5e-13

# And checking a new instance:

In [14]: Bacteria(2).min_bacteria_size                                                                                    
Out[14]: 50.0
```

Note that te way properties work, you can't retrieve the transformed value from the *class* itself with `Bacteria.min_bacteria_size`: that will retrieve the property object itself. It is possible to create an object just like a property, but that will return the guarded value instead of itself when called on the class - but unless you really need this, or if you will want this for several classes and values, it would be overcomplicate the code. You can easily just invert the logic, and keep the class attribute value in fentometres, and use the property to get the multiplied meter value - that way the human friendly value is readl available as a simple class attribute, just like the multiplied value is in this implementation:

```
In [15]: Bacteria.min_bacteria_size                                                                                       
Out[15]: <property at 0x7fa61e469f40>

In [16]: Bacteria.min_bacteria_size_raw                                                                                   
Out[16]: 5e-13
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for classmethod in python.

```py
class A:
    a = 3

    @classmethod
    def set_a(cls, value):
        cls.a = value * 10  # or whatever calculation

    def update_a(self): # use in other functions as normal
        self.set_a(10)

a = A()
a.set_a(3) # use classmethod
print(A.a) # 30
a.update_a() # or normal
print(A.a) # 100
```

Comment: there is no need for these getters and setters workarounds. Just set the attribute in the class itself: `A.a = 10`

Comment: It's just a personal preference but even if someone doesn't wants to use setters instead of `A.a = 10`, I personally prefer `self.__class__.a = 10`. Reasoning behind that is I don't want to reference class name inside of class methods. Due to renaming (and visual map) purposes. But yeah you're right there's no need for setters but I disagree that it's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SetSize:
    def __init__(self, storage_name):
        self.storage_name = storage_name  

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.storage_name] = value * 10 ** -15


class Bacteria(Contour):
   min_bacteria_size = SetSize(‘min_bacteria_size’)
```

I couldn’t test it but this idea would help you I think.

Comment: You should test this.